# Bayesian SEM: Selecting (Weakly) Informative Prior

Tags: bayesian, structural-equation-modeling, prior

I am looking for recommendations regarding how to  select informative (or minimally weakly informative) priors for a Bayesian SEM model? I have no specific predictions with regards to my model / individual parameters. I am running my models in r using the 'blavaan' package.

Alternatively, if I rely on the default priors will this bias my results?

Dr. Merkle's website has been extremely helpful in understanding how to specify priors https://ecmerkle.github.io/blavaan/articles/prior.html -  I am just unclear on how to select meaningful priors for my specific parameters.

Thank you very much.